# How to keep original jqgrid width when applying columnchooser?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, column-chooser

I am using jQgrid 4.7.0 version. When I apply 'Remove all' option in 'columnchooser' the grid's width shrinks and hence unable to see even my jQgrid headers and the jQgrid pagers.

Please see the same issue [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser3.htm).

I set

```
`height: 'auto', autoWidth:'true', shrinkToFit : true, forceToFit:true`
```

in my jQgrid property

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

By the way my old demo which you referenced use jqGrid 4.3.1 and not jqGrid 4.7.0. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) as the fork of jqGrid based on the code of jqGrid 4.7.0 since almost one year. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.11.0. I made many changes and enhancements described in readmes to every from published version and [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). The new version would hold the width of the grid on hiding of some (or even all) columns it you would use fixed value for the `width` during creating of it.

I created the demo http://jsfiddle.net/kbhmg9nq/ which shows the results. It uses

```
width: 700
```

and it displays empty grid of the the same width as before if one would hide all the columns:

[image]

Thus I suggest you to upgrade to free jqGrid.